# Not able to plot voltages graph (v1 vs v2) in a website using esp32 and arduino

Tags: javascript, html, arduino, chart.js, esp32

I have started learning to build some good websites. In one of my projects, I wanted to **display two voltages** (named "*POTvalue1" & "POTvalue2*") on a **website**. The values of both the voltages will vary using a **potentiometer**.

Till here I have written an Arduino script and it is working perfectly fine. The problem arose when I tried to plot a graph (*POTvalue1 vs POTvalue2*  OR *V1 vs V2*) using ***chart.js***. I tried to plot the graph,  but the code seemed to be wrong. *The graph wasn't showing any values neither on the x-axis nor on the y-axis. I wanted to plot a live graph on the website and the values changes when I change the value of the potentiometer.*

**It will be very helpful if someone can help me.**

*I am attaching both the Arduino code and HTML code here...*

```
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <WebSocketsServer.h>
#include "webpage.h"

WebServer server(80);
WebSocketsServer webSocket = WebSocketsServer(81);
String JSONtxt;
const char* ssid = "realme 6i";
const char* password = "112233456789";
const int potPin1 = 34;
const int potPin2 = 35;
int offset = -10;
float v = 0;
float i = 0;
void handleRoot()
{
 server.send(200, "text/html", webpageCode); //send webpage to the web browser
}

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print("."); delay(500);  
  }
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  Serial.print(" Local IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  
  server.on("/", handleRoot);
  server.begin(); 
  webSocket.begin();
  
}
void loop() 
{
  webSocket.loop(); server.handleClient();
  int volt1 = analogRead(35);
  int volt2 = analogRead(34);
  double voltage1 = map(volt1, 0,1023,0,2500)+offset;
  double voltage2 = map(volt2, 0,1023, 0, 2500)+offset;
  String voltage1String = String(float(voltage1)/500.0);
  String voltage2String = String(float(voltage2)/500.0);
  JSONtxt = "{\"POT1\":\""+voltage1String+"\",";
  JSONtxt += "\"POT2\":\""+voltage2String+"\"}";
  webSocket.broadcastTXT(JSONtxt);
  String v1 = voltage1String;
  Serial.print("voltage v1 = ");
  Serial.println(v1);
  String v2 = voltage2String;
  Serial.print("voltage v2 = ");
  Serial.println(v2);


  delay(500);
}
```

**And the webpage script**

```
R"=====(
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    
    <style>
    #dynRectangle1
    {
        width:0px;
        height:12px;
        top: 9px;
        background-color: red;
        z-index: -1;
        margin-top:8px;
    }

     #dynRectangle2
    {
        width:0px;
        height:12px;
        top: 9px;
        background-color: red;
        z-index: -1;
        margin-top:8px;
    }
    body   {background-color:rgba(128,128,128,0.322); font-family:calibri}
    h1     {font-size: 40px; color: black; text-align: center}
    h2     {font-size: 30px; color: blue}
    h3     {font-size: 17px; color:blue}
    div.h1 {background-color: whitesmoke;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {

      var dps = [];   //dataPoints. 

      var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
        title :{
            text: "Graph"
        },
        axisX: {                        
            title: "V1"
        },
        axisY: {                        
            title: "V2"
        },
        data: [{
            type: "spline",
            dataPoints : dps
        }]
      });

      chart.render();
      var xVal = dps.length + 1;
      var yVal = dps.length + 1;    
      var updateInterval = 1000;

      var updateChart = function () {
        
        
        yVal = POTvalue1;
        dps.push({x: xVal,y: yVal});
        
        xval = POTvalue2;
        if (dps.length >  10 )
        {
            dps.shift();                
        }

        chart.render();     


};

setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval); 
}
</script>
<script type=" " src=" "></script>
    

</head>
<body>
    
    <h1><div class="h1">Voltage V1</div></h1>
    <h2>
        POT voltage 1: <span style="color:rgb(216, 3, 3)" id="POTvalue1">0</span> V  
    </h2>
    <h3>
        0V &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; 3.5V
        <div id="dynRectangle1"></div>
    </h3>
    
    
    <h1><div class="h1">Voltage V2</div></h1>
    <h2>
        POT voltage 2: <span style="color:rgb(216, 3, 3)" id="POTvalue2">0</span> V  
    </h2>
    <h3>
        0V &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
        &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; 3.5V
        <div id="dynRectangle2"></div>
    </h3>

    
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<script>
  InitWebSocket()
  function InitWebSocket()
  {
    websock = new WebSocket('ws://'+window.location.hostname+':81/');
    websock.onmessage=function(evt)
    {
       JSONobj = JSON.parse(evt.data);
       document.getElementById('POTvalue1').innerHTML = JSONobj.POT1;
       var pot1 = parseInt(JSONobj.POT1 * 135);
       document.getElementById("dynRectangle1").style.width = pot1+"px";
       
       document.getElementById('POTvalue2').innerHTML = JSONobj.POT2;
       var pot2 = parseInt(JSONobj.POT2 * 135);
       document.getElementById("dynRectangle2").style.width = pot2+"px";
    }
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
)=====";
```

**Please help me out**
Elements

1. esp32
2. potentimeter*1
3. diode*1
4. resistor 10K*1
5. voltage sensor*2

Comment: Hi @Anindya, welcome to Stack Overflow. You said you had problems with chart.js but I don't see any references to chart.js in the code you posted or even any attempt to graph anything. If you'd like help with the problem you said you had, please edit the question to share the code that you need help with.

Comment: @romkey you are right, I did a mistake in uploading the code. Actually, by mistake, I uploaded the previous version of the code. I have corrected this time. Please have a look and thanks for pointing out my mistakes.